# Setting up email series in mailgun

Tags: automation, mailgun, activecampaign

I need to set up series of emails with time delays in mailgun.

I'm not sure this is possible without connecting to a CRM like ActiveCampaign, Mailchimp, etc.

If it's possible, can anyone share how it works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are a developer, I would do it yourself (create an app that send the emails over MG). This detailed description may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150905/can-i-send-email-with-mailgun-sandbox-domain-under-my-local-os/68542876#68542876

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun is a transactional email service that gives you the ability to send emails from your own web applications. If you want to create a drip campaign like you mentioned, you’d have to add such logic to your web application either through a cron-like task or similar.

There is Mailjet from the same company that offers email automation (another name for drip emails). While I don’t have hands on experience with Mailjet like I do Mailgun, it should be a WYSIWYG interface like what you’re interested in.

At the end of the day it really comes down to what you’re after. Do you want to add email sending to your own applications where you design every aspect of the sending and scheduling logic, or do you want a tool available and ready to go.

Best,